# What are some handy tricks for submitting Grails forms?

Tags: forms, grails, groovy, gsp

Everybody's aware of passing parameters to a controller via a html form:

```
<g:form action="save">
  <g:textField name="text1" />
</g:form>
```

And I'm vaguely aware of being able to structure these parameters into some sort of object notation in Grails:

```
<g:form action="save">
  <g:textField name="text.a" />
  <g:textField name="text.b" />
</g:form>
```

With very little idea how they are structured in the controller (objects? hashmaps? I recall having to use .value at some point using the latter example).

So I guess this question is really two questions:

1. How does Grails handle parameters in object notation like the second example? Can you stick them into arrays too?
2. What are some other tricks regarding form submission and its parameters that can make forms with very complex and iterative data trivial to handle in the controller? For instance, ATG allows you to bind form fields to beans and **walk its entire property graph** to find the property you need to set.

Answer (score 0):

The second notation `"text.a"` is used to disambiguate data conversion from properties to domain objects. For example, if you have 2 domain objects each with a property `"a"`, if you do `domObj1.properties = params` and `domObj2.properties = params` the value will go to both domain objects which may not be what you want. So in your view you should have variables domObj1.a and domObj2.a and in your grails controller you can instantiate using `def domObj1 = new DomObj1(params["domObj1"])`

By your second question if you mean whether you can iterate over objects, you very well can, using GPath syntax in a ${} wrapper, for e.g check out the code in the id property below.

```
<td><g:remoteLink controller="device" action="getDevice" id="${objInstance.prop1.prop2.id}" update="propDetail">${fieldValue(bean: objInstance.prop1, field: "prop1")}</g:remoteLink></td>
```

The example above also shows an ajax way of form submission from grails gsp.